# create entry-point script to get all env variables starting with VUE_APP_ and take it's value

Tags: docker, dockerfile, shell-script, bash

I would like to Dockerize my existing vuejs app for staging , production and I used multi staged approach to create my app container and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and this is my,

#### Dockerfile

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

LABEL maintainer="servers@xpl.com"

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

LABEL maintainer="servers@xpl.com"

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/ /app/dist/

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 80
```

I don't want to create `docker-compose.yml` file to assign anything and my question would be like , Create `.env` file with hardcoded values.

**i.e**

```
VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_DOMAIN=VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_DOMAIN
```

1 .When running npm run build it'll put VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_DOMAIN in the dest files.

2 .We need to know which file. Probably index.html I believe.

3 .We create entry-point.sh script will get all env variables starting with `VUE_APP_` and take it's value. And then using **`sed`** command we find and replace those hard coded variable placeholders in index.html.
And finally start Nginx.

**I was stuck on step 3.**

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you clarify it?  Also, what have you tried and why didn't it work?  Also, the whole thing may be solved with the [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) command.

Comment: I need to create my existing vue app on docker to deploy it to production so for that I created my Dockerfile which is included in top and now my question is how can I pass env values ? so I created a file called .env to hard coded env values to it will also build during npm build command then I can use sed command to find and replace with actual value . this is the scenario how can I do that ?

Comment: The [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) instruction. If you just need an environment variable defined when the container is run, then you can do that when running the container via docker-compose or the docker run command.

Comment: I need to do the 3rd step in my question ``` 3 .We create entry-point.sh script will get all env variables starting with VUE_APP_ and take it's value. And then using sed command we find and replace those hard coded variable placeholders in index.html. And finally start Nginx.  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not clear what your trying to do (the script you have so far for the bit you are having trouble with would probably be handy), I *think* you are essentially just trying to parse your environment and manipulate the variables at the start of your script?

I don't see why add something like this to the first line of your script wouldn't work:

```
eval $(typeset -p | grep -E 'declare -x VUE_APP_' | sed -e 's#declare -x VUE_APP_#export VUE_APP_#g')
```

But then I also don't know what shell you're running or anything else about the container, so I'm not sure..

Comment: thanks @hvindin